# I have the following code to set the source sheet as the book I am working in

Tags: excel, vba

However I keep getting the error "Subscipt out of range" unsure whats going wrong?
My code jumps back and forth from the source and the destination book, but the source variable is consistent amounst the entire module. I am worried it keeps changing as it jumps?

```
Property Get wsSrc() As Worksheet
    Set wsSrc = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
End Property
```

Comment: Not nearly enough info to troubleshoot.  Best guess is that you're calling this class property when the active workbook is changing, and one of the workbooks doesn't have a sheet named "Sheet1"

Comment: Might be better to provide a little more context.  Where is this property defined, and how is it used?  If the active workbook changes then of course the returned sheet will be from the currently-active workbook (assuming there is a matching worksheet).  If you need the workbook fixed to some point in time then you'll need a global variable to keep it in, and have your property Get refer to that variable, instead of the "live" `ActiveWorkbook`